# how do i make the flutter textfield shorter and not goes behind the clear button?

Tags: flutter, dart

how do i make the textfield shorter and not goes behind the clear button?

[image]

```
Stack(
                    alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerEnd,
                    children: [
                      TextField(
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
                        controller: controller,
                        focusNode: focusNode,
                        autofocus: true,
                        onChanged: (text) {
                          text.length >= 4
                            ?  provider.fetchBySearchName(text)
                            :  buildNoData();
                        },
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Search',
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                            // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                            // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          )
                        ),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: clearText, 
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        icon: Icon(Icons.cancel_outlined)
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
```

Answer (score 5):

Try below code and use [**`suffixIcon`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/suffixIcon.html) for text overlapping issue

```
TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'Search',
          hintText: 'Search Here',
          suffixIcon: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              print('Button Pressed');
              //put your clear function here
            },
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.cancel_outlined,
            ),
          ),
          /*suffixIcon: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
               print('Button Pressed');
              //put your clear function here
            },
            child: Icon(
              Icons.cancel_outlined,
            ),
          ),*/
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        ),
      ),
```

Result

[image]

Comment: thanks! then how do i add a textController.clear() on pressing cancel?

Comment: use IconButton instead of Icon on your suffixIcon then you have onPressed

Comment: @phongyewtong check my updated answer, you used `IconButton` or `InkWell` or `GestureDetector` widgets

Comment: @phongyewtong if your problem has been solved accept and upvote my answer

Answer (score 0):

put IconButton on suffixIcon.

```
TextField(
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
                    controller: controller,
                    focusNode: focusNode,
                    autofocus: true,
                    onChanged: (text) {
                      text.length >= 4
                        ?  provider.fetchBySearchName(text)
                        :  buildNoData();
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        onPressed: clearText, 
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        icon: Icon(Icons.cancel_outlined)
                      ),
                      labelText: 'Search',
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                        // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                        // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      )
                    ),
                  ),
```